# OpenCV: Get only black contours in a binary image with findContours

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am new to OpenCV, so please bear with me.

Currently, I get contours of both white and black things in my binary image. I only want black contours though (so where the value is 0). Is there some kind of setting I can adjust to get this result? Or can I filter them?

Also: cv.findContours() does return both the contours and a hierarchy. What is hierarchy used for?

And lastsly: Contours seemingly consist of an array with multiple coordinates. What do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

cv2.findContours finds all the contours in your image. Some are internal, some are external, some are nested inside other contours.

For this reason the method returns multiple coordinates. 
Hierarchy is a vector that contains information about these different levels of contours extracted (external, nested, internal etc..).

You can however set a [`retrievalMode`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) to filter contours based on hierarchy.

Under no circumstances they contain information about color so you need to filter them in some way.

I might add that a sensible thing you can do is filter the image before getting contours, so you find contours only in the mask you create, based on the color or range of colours of your choice (see `cv2.inRange`)

Comment: As far as I understand, I can create a mask with cv2.inRange? This mask (at least in the example I found in the docs) seems to be binary then. My image is binary to begin with though. What would that mask help me do?

Comment: you create the mask and pass it in `cv2.findContours` as you would do it with the image and it will find contours in that mask. I don't know if that is ideal for your use case. That's one way you can tackle the problem. If it doesn't suit your application you can also extract the contours first then filter them after.

Comment: So when I pass a mask onto cv2.findCotours, it does only find (i.e.) the black contours and not the white ones?

Comment: The mask is basically the original image without all the colours that you cut out. When you pass the mask it will find all the contours it can, but inside the mask, not the image.

Comment: Yeees, that's what I already got, but it doesn't answer my question. When I have a circle and mask exactly that circle (not the hole) and pass that mask onto findContours(), it won't return a contour for the hole, right?

Comment: If there is contrast it will return the contours. I don't know how your images are, try this approach and see if it is the right one. Otherwise you filter the contours after the findContours without masking.

Comment: Well, since they are already binary, a mask won't help. But do you know how to determine the colour within a contour?

Comment: if the image is binary how there are black and white contours? can you publish an example image you are working with?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not allowed to share the images. But it's as simple as: Go into Paint, make a black dot in the middle and use findContours() on it. It will tell you that it found two. One for the white space and one for the dot.